# How many edge-disjoint cycles of length 3 are in the complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory, cycles, algorithms

A couple of questions related to edge-disjoint cycles.

Let $K_n = (V,E)$ be the complete graph on $|V|=n$ nodes.  Two cycles are 'edge disjoint' if they do not share any edges.

- What is the size of the largest collection of edge-disjoint cycles of length 3 in Kn?
- Consider a spanning tree sub-graph of $K_n$ (so any spanning tree on $n$ nodes).  Is there an efficient algorithm for adding $c$ edges such that each edge creates a cycle of length 3 and is edge-disjoint with all other cycles added?

Any references or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

thanks...

Comment: If I understand the second question correctly, you want $c\le n/2$?

Comment: The first question does not quite make sense. Do you want the size of the maximal collection of edge-disjoint triangles?


Comment: $n \equiv 1,3 \mod 6$ iff there is a Steiner triple system on $n$ points, which is equivalent to a partition of the edges of $K_n$ into triangles.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  Yes, I meant the size of the maximal collection of edge-disjoint triangles. I updated the post accordingly.  For the maximum value of c in the second question, that would be upper bounded by the answer to the first question.

Thanks for the Steiner triple reference, I will look into that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The maximum number of edge-disjoint triangles in a complete graph is determined by:

Joel Spencer.
Maximal consistent families of triples. 
J. Combinatorial Theory, 5 1968 1–8.